# Can more than one keylistener event be registered in Java (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, exception

I am trying to validate some textfield input data to be within a range of values.

I have two JTextFields in my simple GUI, and have registered the following:

```
    ID1_Txt_Input.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            String text = validateInput(textField.getText(),1,254);
            textField.setText(text);
         }
        });

    ID2_Txt_Input.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            String text = validateInput(textField.getText(),0,65535);
            textField.setText(text);
         }
        });
```

I then have a simple validation method as follows:

```
public String validateInput( String s, int val_min, int val_max )
{
    String output = "";
    int val = 0;
    try {
        val = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ne) {
        output = "";
    }

    if( val < val_min )
    {
        output = "";
    }
    else if( val > val_max )
    {
        val /= 10;
        output = (String.valueOf(val));
    }
    else{
        output = s;
    }

    return output;
};
```

**What I am seeing:** The first textfield is validating properly, only allowing a number between 1-254 to be entered, and auto-clearing when a non-number is entered.  The second textfield is NOT validating properly.

I am very new to Java, so if I am making a glaring error in how I am approaching this problem, I would appreciate the advice.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that would be, as a user, incredibly annoying.  Not mention, you may actually trigger a mutation exception and or see you updates completely ignored, not to mention what would happen if someone pasted text into the field...

Real time validation of this type is best done through the use of a `DocumentFilter`, which will allow to filter the values being added/removed to a `Document` before they occur

Take a look at [Implementing a `DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for details and [MDP's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for examples

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  As I said, I am very, very new at this...  I will look into the DocumentFilter stuff.

Comment: @Nanomurf Once you get your head around it, `DocumentFilter` is really powerful ;)